# iOS Swift - Refreshing entire application after button press

Tags: ios, swift, refresh, segue, unwind-segue

I have a modally presented View Controller called `ChangeViewController` that allows the user to change some information regarding his/her profile. When the user is done, the 'ACCEPT CHANGES' button is pressed and I use an unwind segue to exit out of the `ChangeViewController` and go back to the main screen.

Is it possible for me to refresh the data of the entire app before performing this unwind segue? As of now, the information on the home screen and other screens remains unchanged after user modifications. Only after an app reboot does the information update. Is there a way to programmatically 'reboot' so all View Controllers are up to date? More specifically, is there a way to call the `viewDidLoad` functions of all View Controllers so their data is updated?

Solutions in Swift preferred. Thank you!

Comment: Always load the data from the data store (where you store these user preferences) and call the data showing method from viewWillAppear

Comment: Do you think using `viewWillAppear` to load the data will affect the performance of my app because it will called very often?

Answer (score 1):

I oftentimes updateUI after a user changes with a function like this. This is pretty simple, and you just call the function whenever your UI is updated.

```
func updateUI() {
    // Redraw your labels, update your UIElements, do what you have to do
}
```

A way you can call this function from a modally presented ViewController without closing the app is with delegation, since modal presentation does not throw the old ViewController out of the stack and heap, Delegation works like this:

In your modal controller:

```
protocol ChangeViewControllerDelegat: class {
    func updateUI(sender:UIButton)
}

class ChangeViewController: UIViewController {

weak var delegate: ChangeViewControllerDelegat?

func opChangingUserSettings() {
     // Change settings with your code

     // tell your ViewController to do it. 
     delegate?.updateUI()
}
```

in your mainVC

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ExtensionViewControllerDelegate {
       func updateUI() {
        // Redraw your labels, update your UIElements, do what you have to do
       }
}
```

Hope that helps!

By the way, are you trying to change language by any chance on the fly? If so, I can show you how to do that. If not, and If I understand your question, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the local notification for your scenario.

As in, when the user is done with the changes and presses the button to accept the changes, there you can post a local notification to reload the data.
And you can listen to that notification in all of your viewControllers and reload the data there, like if it is a table view then you can simply call the reloadData method on tableview to achieve it.